# Find files with non-printing characters (null bytes)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I have got the log of my application with a field that contains strange characters.
I see these characters only when I use `less` command.

I tried to copy the result of my line of code in a text file and what I see is

```
CTP_OUT=^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to find these null characters. I have tried with a `grep` command but it didn't show anything

Comment: What do you want to convert it *to*? In that particular example, `^@` is how `less` displays a null byte (i.e. 8 zero bits in a row). Perhaps the actual question here "is there a better tool than `less` for viewing binary data?" Or perhaps what you're really interested in is "why am I getting null bytes in my output?"

Comment: No, I'd like to know if there is a way to find these null characters. For example, if I got 10 files, how can I search ^@ ? I have tried with a grep command but it didn't show anything

Comment: Unfortunately, I can confirm that grep is not good at searching null characters. I assume that it is intended to search strings and internally uses the null as the string delimiter (the standard C way). So no hope that is can be able to detect a null byte in a file. But this [question](https://superuser.com/q/845268) from SuperUser could help.

Comment: Then you may need a tool written in a language that doesn't use nul-terminated strings, such as [ack](https://beyondgrep.com/)? (Or write your own nul-sensitive tool in C)

Comment: If it contains NULs then it is not a text file per POSIX (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) so you should not expect to be able to use tools on it that operate on text files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hardly believe it, I might write an answer involving `cat`!

The characters you are observing are *non-printable* characters which are often written in [Carret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation). The Caret notation of a character is a way to visualize non-printable characters. As mentioned in the OP, `^@` is the representation of `NULL`.

If your file has non-printable characters, you can visualize them using `cat -vET`:

> **`-E, --show-ends`:**  display `$` at end of each line
>    **`-T, --show-tabs`:**  display `TAB` characters as `^I`
>    **`-v, --show-nonprinting`:** use `^` and `M-` notation, except for `LFD` and `TAB`
>
> **<sub>source: `man cat`</sub>**

I've added the `-E` and `-T` flag to it, to convert everything non-printable.

As `grep` will not output the non-printable characters itself in any form, you have to pipe its output to `cat` to see them. The following example shows all lines containing non-printable characters

**Show all lines with non-printable characters:**

```
$ grep -E '[^[:print:]]' --color=never file | cat -vET
```

Here, the ERE `[^[:print:]]` selects all non-printable characters.

**Show all lines with `NULL`:**

```
$ grep -Pa '\x00' --color=never file | cat -vET
```

Be aware that we need to make use of the Perl regular expressions here as they understand the hexadecimal and octal notation.

> Various control characters can be written in C language style: `\n` matches a newline, `\t` a tab, `\r` a carriage return, `\f` a form feed, etc.
>
> More generally, `\nnn`, where `nnn` is a string of three octal digits, matches the character whose native code point is `nnn`. You can easily run into trouble if you don't have exactly three digits. So always use three, or since Perl 5.14, you can use `\o{...}` to specify any number of octal digits.
>
> Similarly, `\xnn`, where `nn` are hexadecimal digits, matches the character whose native ordinal is `nn`. Again, not using exactly two digits is a recipe for disaster, but you can use `\x{...}` to specify any number of hex digits.
>
> **<sub>source: [Perl 5 version 26.1 documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)</sub>**

An example:

```
$ printf 'foo\012\011\011bar\014\010\012foobar\012\011\000\013\000car\012\011\011\011\012' > test.txt
$ cat test.txt
foo
                bar

foobar

        car
```

If we now use `grep` alone, we get the following:

```
$ grep -Pa '\x00' --color=never test.txt

        car
```

But piping it to `cat` allows us to visualize the control characters:

```
$ grep -Pa '\x00' --color=never test.txt | cat -vET
^I^@^K^@car$
```

**Why `--color=never`:** If your grep is tuned to have `--color=auto` or `--color=always` it will add extra control characters to be interpreted as color for the terminal. And this might confuse you by the content.

```
$ grep -Pa '\x00' --color=always test.txt | cat -vET
^I^[[01;31m^[[K^@^[[m^[[K^K^[[01;31m^[[K^@^[[m^[[Kcar$
```

Comment: Imo this is a useless use of cat :P ... Generally you can't answer this independently of encoding of the logfile (utf8?) and the locale in use

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not aware of any encodings where a long string of NULL bytes would represent anything other than a long string of NULL bytes. Whatever is generating this file is not outputting human-readable text.

Comment: Is the question about non printable characters or about null bytes in particular? In the latter case the title should be changed

Answer (score 7):

`sed` can.

```
 sed -n '/\x0/ { s/\x0/<NUL>/g; p}' file
```

`-n` skips printing any output unless explicitly requested.
`/\x0/` selects for only lines with null bytes.
`{...}` encapsulates multiple commands, so that they can be collectively applied always and only when the `/\x0/` has detected a null on the line.
`s/\x0/<NUL>/g;` substitutes in a new, visible value for the null bytes. You could make it whatever you want - I used `<NUL>` as something both reasonably obvious and yet unlikely to occur otherwise. You should probably grep the file for it first to be sure the pattern doesn't exist before using it.
`p;` causes lines that have been edited (because they had a null byte) to show.

This basically makes `sed` an effective `grep` for nulls.